# Does Remak-Krull-Schmidt implies structure theorem for fg modules over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Is the [structure theorem on f.g. modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) implied by the [Remak-Krull-Schmidt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem)? Or are there f.g. modules over PIDs for which the latter theorem fails?

Answer (score 1):

According to section $5.7$ of Popescu, Abelian Categories,

> **Thm 7.5:** Any *finite* object has a unique KRS-decomposition.

In the case of commutative semiartinian rings a module is *finite* iff is noetherian. In general, I think that that section is a very good reading.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please make your answer more self-contained. First, what is semiartinian and noetherian and its relation to PIDs, and second the book you cite seems to be highly advanced and category theoretic, and you cite something from page 350 onwards, surely it might be a good read, but necessary to answer my question? My background is just basic algebra, and I am not quite sure if your answer confirms my guessed relationship between fg modules and KRS thm...