# Does there exist a non-trival set $W$ such that $W\times W \cong W\times W\times W$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

1. Does there exist a non-trival set $W$ such that $W\times W \cong W\times W\times W$ where $\times$ is the exterior product?
2. Consider $R^2$ and $R^3$, I don't think they were isomorphism to each other, but I wasn't sure how to prove their order(i.e. suppose $|R|=\omega$)
3. Could you find a subspace $W$ of $R$ or $C$(fields) such that $W$ was the smallest (in order) non trival set such that $W\times W \cong W\times W\times W$?

   - $\cong$ here meant for bijection, and was used to emphasize the another question: if $W$ was a field, could the bijection also be a ring homomorphism?

Comment: What do yuo mean by $\cong$, exactly?

Comment: The product of two infinite numerable sets is numerable.

Comment: If $W$ is a field, then $W \times W$ and $W \times W \times W$ are vector spaces. There would be no vector space isomorphism because they have a different dimension over $W$, hence no ring isomorphism.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 thank you. But could there be an bijection between $R^2$ and $R^3$?(I mean when $W$ was filed of infinite order)

Comment: Yes. If $X$ is an infinite set, then there is a set bijection between $X$ and $X^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Asking if there's a bijection, and asking whether there can be a field isomorphism, are very different questions. Are you asking about one or both.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine thank you. Existence of the bijection first, and then the isomorphism. Joe Johnson 126 has answered the question about the isomorphism already.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Thank you, so I just need to send the $A\times A$ to $A^2\times A$ right? Could you send me the proof? I was looking for a transformation between spaces of different dimensions, and I wasn't sure how to do the exact construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the category of sets, any bijection $A \to A \times A$ is an isomorphism. In particular, take $A= \mathbb N$. Then define $f:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by $(n,m) \mapsto 2^n \cdot 3^m$.

---

If $A$ is a field, there are some problems. For example, if you define $(a,b) \cdot (c,d)=(ac,bd)$, then $A \times A$ is most certainly not a field, since $(1,0) \cdot (0,1)=0$.

---

One way to "make this work" is that if you work in the category of $R$-modules, and consider $\otimes$ instead (which is reasonable, I think) then you can take $R \otimes_R R \cong R$ to be $(a \otimes b) \mapsto ab$ which is always an isomorphism of modules.

Comment: Thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000739/how-to-write-down-a-bijection-from-mathbb-n-onto-mathbb-n-times-mathbb-n-ti?noredirect=1&lq=1 Patrick Stevens's answer provided a solution on $N$ by using Cantor pairing function, could it also be used on $R$? Further, what if $W$ is an non ordered field(A subspace in $C$)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of cancelletion of the direct product have been deeply studied and in most of cases finds an answer in the [Krull-Remak-Schmidt Theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Krull-Remak-Schmidt_theorem).

A list of relevant links is the following:

[Cancellation of Direct Product in Grp](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042904/cancellation-of-direct-product-in-grp).

[On cancellation in Groups.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317133?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

[Does Remak-Krull-Schmidt implies structure theorem for fg modules over PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855585/does-remak-krull-schmidt-implies-structure-theorem-for-fg-modules-over-pid/2855599#2855599).